# Can $\{a^mb^nc^n\mid m,n \ge 1\}$ be proved non-regular using the pumping lemma?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, pumping-lemma

$\{a^mb^nc^n\mid m,n \ge 1\}$ intuitively seems like a non-regular language. It looks like the machine needs to remember the number of $b$s (which isn't limited). The [pumping lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages) can be used to prove a language is non-regular. In reference to the Wikipedia article linked (see "Use of Lemma"), every string I have tried doesn't give a contradiction. For example, a string like $a^1b^pc^p$ (where $p$ is the pumping length) seems to nicely split into $x = \varepsilon$, $y = a^1$, $z = b^pc^p$. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4):

You've forgotten that $y$ can be pumped any number of times, including zero. The string $xy^0z = b^pc^p$ is not in the language.

Comment: Well, what about $x = a$, $y = a$, $z = b^pc^p$? There is more missed in [revision 3](https://cs.stackexchange.com/revisions/30552/3) than picking a suitable $x$, and possibly something more important to understanding the scope of the pumping lemma for regular languages.

Comment: Greybeard it says “for every string in the language L”. There’s one string leading to a counter example, that’s enough.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Say $N$ is the constant of the pumping lemma, and consider $\sigma = a b^N c^N \in L$ and $\lvert \sigma \rvert = 2 N + 1 \ge N$. By the lemma, you can write $\sigma = \alpha \beta \gamma$, such that $\lvert \alpha \beta \rvert \le N$ with $\beta \ne \epsilon$ such that for all $k \ge 0$ it is $\alpha \beta^k \gamma \in L$. Now $\beta$ must be composed of only one symbol (in this case, as $\lvert \alpha \beta \rvert \le N$, it has to be only $a$ or some $b$s) as otherwise $\alpha \beta^k \gamma$ for $k > 1$ isn't of the right form ($a$s followed by $b$s followed by $c$s). Now $\alpha = \epsilon$, $\beta = a$ is impossible, because in that case you's have $\alpha \beta^0 \gamma = b^N c^N \notin L$. But $\beta$ just $b$s with $k \ne 1$ gives a string with number of $b$s and $c$s different, thus not in $L$. No division into $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ works, the language fails the pumping lemma, it can't be regular.

Make sure you understand the lemma and it's use. Your proof is by contradiction, you need to prove the lemma *doesn't* apply. The lemma states that there is a constant $N > 0$ (i.e., you *can't* assume anything about $N$, just know it is positive) such that *all* strings in the regular language that are longer than $N$ (to get a contradiction, you can pick *any* convenient string that is long enough) *can* be divided into three parts with the given restrictions (i.e., you don't get to pick a convenient division, you have to prove *none* works), for that division *all* $k \ge 0$ pumpings belong to the language (given any division, you can pick some $k \ne 1$ that makes the pumped string not in the language).

Answer (score 0):

The pumping Lemma is very abstract, yet very obvious if you check where it comes from.

If L is a regular language then there is a finite state machine with exactly P states. If you examine a string w of P or more symbols, then after  processing P symbols you must have entered the same state twice. Say the first state entered twice is X, then w = axb where the string a moves from the initial state S to X, x moves from X back to X, and if w is in the language, then b moves from X to an accepting state. And the length of ax is at most P.

Processing ab would also move from S to X to an accepting state. axxb would move from S to X to X to X to an accepting state and so on. And that’s the pumping Lemma: If w is long enough then you must have entered a loop, and the string causing the loop can be repeated any number of times.

That’s why $ab^nc^n$ gives a counter example: Because the loop must contain a sequence of b’s or c’s; since one a is needed, it cannot be part of any loop. And that’s why $a^2b^nc^n$ doesn’t give a counter example: Because the second a forms a loop and therefore can be repeated any number of times, including zero times.

Answer (score -1):

$S = a^Pb^{PM}c^{PM}$. It can be divided in $S = xyz$ where $x = \epsilon, y = a^P, z = b^{PM}c^{PM}$ which satisfies the following conditions:
$$ |xy| \le P $$
$$ xy^iz \in L $$
$$ |y| >= 1 $$
The middle condition is satisfied because the length of a is irrelevant to the length of b and c.

But, this doesn’t mean that a language is regular. The pumping lemma in simple words only says that: each regular language that can be represented with an automaton that has |finiteStates| = $x$, and the sequence it accepts is of length > $x$ then according to the pigeon-hole theorem,  at least one state is looping.

The pumping lemma does not work both ways. Therefore a language that satisfies it is not necessarily regular. It only means that the ones with variable length that don't satisfy it are irregular.

Comment: $P$ can be as big as you want, the lemma claims that there's pumping length $P > 1$ such that for every string $S$ of the language longer than $P$ the rest of the statements are valid. So we simply just choose $P > 1$.

Comment: I'm sorry and thank you, it is |y| >= 1. My mistake